# HTML Table Isn't Using Bootstrap Formatting As Per kableExtra

Tags: html, r, html-table, r-markdown, kableextra

I would like to create a striped html table.  [As you can see in this picture, it is not formatting as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDS5V.png).  Any tips on how to fix this?

EDIT: I think it has something to do with the doc setup - as at one point it was coming out with the stripes.  I'm not sure what change I made that caused the problem

````
---
title: "Creating a Draft Pick Value Chart"
author: "Tirdod Behbehani"
date: July 5, 2021
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
always_allow_html: true
tables: true
---

```r
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

knitr::kable(list(round1, round2), 
             caption = "NBA Draft Pick Value Table",
             col.names = c("Pick Number", "Pick Value"),
             format = 'html') %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = FALSE, position="left")
```
````

Comment: If I replace your `kable_styling(.)` with `kable_paper("striped", full_width = FALSE, position="left")`, I get the striping. While the two functions are not the same, would that otherwise work for you?

Comment: @r2evans Correct, it was omitted because of the Stack question formatting.  It is in the source doc.  The `kable_paper()` worked for me too - although if possible I'd like to still use `kable_styling()` since it's more aesthetically pleasing.  It was working earlier but not anymore for some reason

Comment: See the edit-suggestion I just made, it's one way to work-around the Stack code-formatting: indentation is sufficient to consider a block "code", so indenting a block that includes the `\`\`\``-fences seems to work.

Comment: @r2evans Good to know - I am new to Stack Overflow thank you

Answer (score 1):

When I use `output: rmarkdown::github_document` and `always_allow_html: true` the stripes from `kable_styling()` show up.  Thank you!